# In Azure container, how can I upload folder containing multiple files and subfolders

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In Storage Container, I only see option to upload individual or multiple files. How can we upload entire folder instead which contains subfolders and files. I am new to Azure and using free tier.
Any guidance would be very valuable, I tried researching but doesn't work for me. I am in portal.azure.com

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using the Azure Portal. You can do that using the free [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/):

[image]

The "Upload folder" action will let you upload a folder from your machine and preserve the containing file and folder structure.